# iOS - I can't add new devices in HockeyApp

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, hockeyapp

I have an app in HockeyApp that I can't add new devices to it. I added the UDID of the device to the provisioning profile and in HockeyApp. And after, when I already uploaded the app, the number of devices is the same! This issue occurs only when I am using HockeyApp application for mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

The HockeyApp application was showing the wrong Provisioning Profile for the app:
[image: HockeyApp for Mac. In the red circle was chosen the wrong Provisioning Profile.]

From there, I discovered that HockeyApp shows the Provisioning Profile that is set in the Build Setting of the target:
[image: Target -> Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile]

I changed from "Automatic" to the Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile that I wanted and it worked. Now the added devices can install the app.

I hope this solution helps someone with the same problem.